# GWTUpload add extra information

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, gwt, upload, gwtupload

I'm using the GWTUpload lib for uploading, which works nicely. On the server side I override the `executeAction()` method of the `UploadAction` class.

But now I would somehow like to send some more information to the server e.g. to map the uploaded stuff to some user.

I'm not using sessions to identify anybody. I would only want to pass a simple extra id from the client to the server while uploading.

Can I modifiy the request parameters on the client side?

Comment: Do you have any insights in this issue? I'm facing the sema problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a few options, everything is described on GWTUpload wiki:

http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/wiki/Servlets

Check "*Sending additional parameters to the servlet*" section.

For example:

**Client side**

```
  MultiUploader u = new MultiUploader();
  u.setServletPath(u.getServletPath() + "?myinfo=whatever");
```

**Server side**

```
  String myInfo = request.getParameter("myinfo");
```